# How apply custom Angular Material Theme without SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material2, angular-material-theming

I'm working in a corporate environment which is making it extremely difficult to try and get SCSS working on our build server. Is there a way to apply custom Angular Material 2 theme using custom color palettes as plain CSS instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material comes with a couple pre-built themes available as plain .css files, [as documented here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme).

If you have an existing custom theme in .scss, you can convert it to .css using the command

`$ node_modules\.bin\node-sass.cmd src\theme.scss > theme.css`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mention that this is a custom theme with custom color palettes. I'll update the question. I will try your suggestion. Thanks.